# What is the path to the kernel header files for the 3.13.0-27-generic kernel?

Tags: lubuntu, vmware-player

I am installing VMware tools on virtual machine Lubuntu and is asking me to enter the path to the kernel header files for the 3.13.0-27-generic kernel? What should I enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the below path,

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-27-generic
```

All the stuffs which are related to a kernal are located inside `/usr/src` directory.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, when compiling, that's a sign that the Makefile can't find the headers because they aren't installed at all. Check:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Those backticks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~. If they are not installed, then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

And then compile again.